# Excel Lookup with multiple criteria with greter than date

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am working on a process where I have data in two tables. First table consist of material no. and the date of delivery for these materials. The second table consist of materials and the document validity in which they are valid. There are multiple contracts with the date of validity. I have to get the document no. in the first table but when I select vlookup it will show simply if it is true or false and will not check the next valid document no. for the material.

The requirement is that I want valid document no. for the materials. The validity depends on the delivery date in Table 1 and Table 2 consist of document details. At the end I want a value and not 'False' statement.

[image: table 1]

[image: 2 tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lookup formula for multiple criteria. But if there is only one valid time span each material then you can use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,A:A,G:G,">="&B:B,H:H,"<="&B:B)
```

[image]

Make sure to remove the `=` sign if the date itself is not included in beeing considered valid.

Note that somehow it looks like start and end dates are mixed up. Start should be lower than end? Also `31.09.2022` is not a date as september has only 30 days. You need to make sure to use real numeric dates or it won't work.

---

//Edit

If you want to be sure that the SUMIF function only shows the exact doc number and never a sum, you can use the following formula instead:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,A:A,G:G,">="&B:B,H:H,"<="&B:B),F:F,0),0)<>0,SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,A:A,G:G,">="&B:B,H:H,"<="&B:B),"double doc found")
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can't this be done via VBA code where it checks the condition for first row and if does not meet criteria then move to next row?

Comment: Why would you do something with VBA that can be done with a formula? If you want to do that with VBA you can. But this is not a free code writing service. So you need to include your attempt in your question. See  [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: I get your logic but why Sumif ? I do e not want the sum of document no. but the exact document no. that satisfies the criteria.

Comment: @RuturajShinde The sum of one exact number **is** that number. Using `SUMIF` only works if the criteria are chosen in a way that the result of the criteria is always exactly one document number, then the sum is that number. See my edit if you need a verification that ensures that it show only exact matches. • In case 2 document numbers are valid it shows "double doc found".

Comment: Works fine. Thank you